# When does the Sequence from midi.Sequencer ends?

Tags: java, midi, duration, javax.sound.midi

Having this simple code which works (but just never ends until I terminated it with ^-c):

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class Foo {

    public void play(int instrument, int note) {
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage first = new ShortMessage();
            first.setMessage(192, 1, instrument, 0);
            MidiEvent changeInstrument = new MidiEvent(first, 1);
            track.add(changeInstrument);

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144, 1, note, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1); //fired on "tick 1"
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128, 1, note, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 8); //fired on "tick 8"
            track.add(noteOff);

            player.setSequence(seq);
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.play(0, 42); 
    }
}
```

The `noteOn` `MidiEvent` is fired on `1 tick` (second argument to `MidiEvent` constructor). The `noteOff` `MidiEvent` is fired on `8 tick`, which means. there should be 7 ticks span. But I can never see the end (end of program). When triggered from cmd, the prompt never returns back unless I forced the process to terminate (with `<ctrl-c>`). Why is that? When is the end of Sequencer and thus end of the program?

EDIT:
It could be caused be opening the Sequencer, but not closing it. So I wanted to close it at the end, but it cannot follow immediately the `player.start()` statement, otherwise it immediately ends. So there must be some delay. It is clunky solution though

```
        ...
        player.setSequence(seq);
        player.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        player.close();
```

After which, the prompt gets back. But is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Midi sequence is finished when Sequencer#isRunning() equals `false`. I think you should close the sequencer object before starting another sequence. Declaring the Sequence object as a class member can give a bit more flexability:

```
// Declare Sequencer as a class member variable and initialize to null.
javax.sound.midi.Sequencer sequencer = null;

public void playMidi(String midiFilePath) {
    // Prevent a new Midi audio file is one is already playing.
    if (sequencer != null) {
        // If sequncer is running get outta here.
        if (sequencer.isRunning()) { 
            return; 
        }
        // Otherwise close the sequencer.
        else { 
            sequencer.close(); 
        }
    }
    // Play the Midi file in its own thread.
    Thread newThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            // Obtains the default Sequencer connected to the System's default device.
            sequencer = javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer();

            // Opens the device, indicating that it should now acquire any
            // system resources it needs and becomes operational.
            if (sequencer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            sequencer.open();

            // Stream in a Midi file
            java.io.InputStream is = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(new File(midiFilePath)));

            // Sets the current sequence on which the sequencer operates.
            // The stream must point to MIDI file data.
            sequencer.setSequence(is);
            is.close();
            // Starts playback of the MIDI data in the currently loaded sequence.
            sequencer.start();
        }
        catch (MidiUnavailableException | IOException | InvalidMidiDataException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("playMidi() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
    newThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the -1 but  this really does not answer the question. Also there is no need to start another thread, sequencer.start() takes care of it internally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a MetaEventListener to catch the "end of sequence" event:

```
  player.addMetaEventListener(metaEvent ->
        {
            if (metaEvent.getType() == 47) // end of sequence
            {
                player.stop();  // Not mandatory according to API doc, but better to have it

                // This is called from the Sequencer thread, NOT from the EDT
                // So we need SwingUtilities if we want to update the UI
                Runnable doRun= new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        doSomethingAfterStop();
                    }
                };
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
            }
        });
```

If you just want to exit your program when sequence is over, just call directly System.exit() in the listener.

Note that if you use Sequencer.setLoopCount(x) with x>0, the end-of-sequence listener is never called, you'll need a UI button (or a timer) to trigger the call to Sequencer.stop().

There are a few tricks to know when using the Java sequencer, if you need example code check out my application JJazzLab-X on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab-X), especially `MusicController.java` in the `MusicController` module.